# Automation of multiple web pages using AutoIT

Tags: autoit

```
#include <string.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPIFiles.au3>
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
#include <Date.au3>
#include <IE.au3>
#include <Inet.au3>

Local $oIE = _IECreate("www.google.com",1,1,1,1)
Sleep(2000)

_IELoadWait($oIE)
Sleep(2000)

$o_form = _IEFormGetObjByName($oIE, "f")
$element = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($o_form,"q")
_IEFormElementSetValue($element,"INDIA")
Sleep(2000)

;~ Send("{ENTER}")
;~ $btn = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($o_form,"gsr")
;~ _IEAction($element,"click")
_IEFormSubmit($o_form)
Sleep(2000)

 _IELinkClickByText($oIE, "India - Wikipedia")
 Sleep(3000)

;~  $Set = _IEFormGetObjByName($o_form,"search")
;~  _IEFormElementSetValue($Set,"MAHARASHTRA")
$OIE1 = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, 'locationurl')
_IELoadWait($OIE1)
Sleep(2000)

MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL,"","New Page",3)
;~ $form = _IEFormGetObjByName($OIE1,"searchform")
;~ $select = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($form,"searchInput")
;~ Sleep(2000)

;~ _IEFormElementSetValue($select,"MAHARASHTRA")
_IELinkClickByText($OIE1,"second-most populous")
```

I am working on web automation using AutoIt. But only two or three pages can be automated using AutoIt. For the further pages the code is not working.

Can anybody help me with the same? How to automate multiple web pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `_IEAttach()` to attach new instances of IE by title, url, handle or other parameters. See [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IEAttach.htm).

```
Local $oIE = _IECreate("www.google.com",1,1,1,1)
_IELoadWait($oIE)
Sleep(2000)
$o_form = _IEFormGetObjByName($oIE, "f")
$element = _IEFormElementGetObjByName($o_form,"q")
_IEFormElementSetValue($element,"INDIA")
Sleep(2000)
_IEFormSubmit($o_form)
Sleep(2000)
 _IELinkClickByText($oIE, "India - Wikipedia")
 Sleep(3000)
$OIE1 = _IEAttach("India - Wikipedia")
_IELoadWait($OIE1)
Sleep(2000)
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL,"","New Page",3)
_IELinkClickByText($OIE1,"second-most populous")
```